# Assigning a value to a 2-d array in a struct is segfaulting

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct _Matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int** elements;
} Matrix;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Matrix *matrix1;
    matrix1 = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

    matrix1->rows = 2;
    matrix1->cols = 2;
    matrix1->elements = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    matrix1->elements[0][0] = 1;
    matrix1->elements[0][1] = 2;
    matrix1->elements[1][0] = 3;
    matrix1->elements[1][1] = 4;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. `matrix1->elements` should be a 2d array/pointer and I'm just trying to assign values to that array.

It segfaults at this line: `matrix1->elements[0][0] = 1;`

Comment: There are no 2D arrays in this code.

Comment: `matrix1->elements[0]` refers to a pointer that has not been allocated. So `matrix1->elements[0][0]` which attempts to dereference that pointer segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
matrix1->elements = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
```

by

```
matrix1->elements = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2);
matrix1->elements[0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
matrix1->elements[1] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
```

The first line allocates memory for `4` `int`s. When you use `element[0]` on that memory, you are treating an `int` like it is an `int*`. There are a series of problems when you do that.

The correct approach is:

1. Allocate memory for `2` `int*`.
2. Allocate memory for each of those `int*` to hold the `int`s.